# SQL query optimization. Estimated vs actual number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, query-optimization

I'm dealing with a query that is taking very long to execute, after taking the query execution plan and live query statistics, I found that there is a huge difference between the estimated and actual number of rows. Why could this happend?

[image: query statistics]

Need help to optimice that query.

Salutes.

Comment: outdated statistics?

Comment: Thank you Sergey, all statistics are updated up to today. Salutes

Comment: There could be several reasons, you need to provide more info. Is this an ad-hoc query? Is it parameterised? Is this a stored proc? Do you pass parameters? The estimates are based on the values provided when the execution plan was built.

Comment: For SQL performance help, please provide the full query, table and index definitions and share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Do you see an improvement `with(option recompile)`?

Answer (score 1):

RE:  "Need help to optimize that query."

Query plan shows 2 clustered index scans.  If those are large data tables, that could be a very big slow down.

Query plan also shows a recommended missing index to be created.

Start with creating the recommended index and see if DRIVER_ALLOCATIONS clustered index scan converts to a seek.  My guess is that -- after the recommended index is added -- the next query plan will show another missing index for the other clustered index scan.

Comment: If you view the *showplan xml* you will see all the index recommendations, if there are more than one - the graphical plan only shows the first one it encounters, which might not necessarily be the most useful recommendation - and all recommended indexes should not be implemented blindly, eg the column ordering is never considered.

Comment: @stu Thank you for how to see all index recommendations.  Totally agree with "should not be implemented blindly".  Optimizer typically prefers heavily covered indexes. Great for SELECT, not so great for INSERT.  Apply or not apply depends on application.